# coulomb's law force calculation using c code

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, sum

I am trying to write a simple program in C to calculate pairwise interaction (Coulomb force) between two chain of beads.Both chains contain 10 beads but one chain is positively charged and the other one is negatively charged. I am reading the x,y,z coordinates and the charge information from two files (Charge from 7th column of atom.psf and coordinates from 6th 7th and 8th columns of beads.pdb). 
Here are the contents of the files:
atom.psf

```
20 !NATOM
       1   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       2   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       3   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       4   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       5   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       6   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       7   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       8   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
       9   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
      10   A   1   CHN    A     A   1.000000        0.0000           0
      11   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      12   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      13   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      14   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      15   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      16   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      17   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      18   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      19   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0
      20   A   2   CHN    A     A  -1.000000        0.0000           0

      18 !NBOND: bonds
       1       2        2       3        3       4        4       5
       5       6        6       7        7       8        8       9
       9      10       11      12       12      13       13      14
      14      15       15      16       16      17       17      18
      18      19       19      20
```

beads.pdb

```
ATOM      1    A CHN     1       1.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      2    A CHN     1       2.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      3    A CHN     1       3.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      4    A CHN     1       4.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      5    A CHN     1       5.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      6    A CHN     1       6.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      7    A CHN     1       7.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      8    A CHN     1       8.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM      9    A CHN     1       9.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     10    A CHN     1      10.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     11    A CHN     2       1.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     12    A CHN     2       2.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     13    A CHN     2       3.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     14    A CHN     2       4.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     15    A CHN     2       5.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     16    A CHN     2       6.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     17    A CHN     2       7.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     18    A CHN     2       8.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     19    A CHN     2       9.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
ATOM     20    A CHN     2      10.000  80.000   0.000  1.00  0.00        A
```

I am having trouble with my final output. At every timestep (t=0 to 100), I need to write the coordinates of 20 atoms. My trial code is given below.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Epsilon0 8.85e-12   // Permittivity of free space (C^2/(N m^2))
#define Constant (1/(4*M_PI*Epsilon0))  // Useful constant
#define gamma 100.0
#define ROW 20

int row, col, j, t;
float x[20], y[20], z[20], q[20], dx, dy, dz, R, Fx, Fy, Fz, F, v, shift;

int main()
{
  FILE *psf=fopen("atom.psf", "r");
  FILE *pdb=fopen("beads.pdb", "r");
  FILE *fout=fopen("out.txt", "a");
  FILE *fout2=fopen("coord.dump", "a");
  fprintf(fout2, "ITEM: TIMESTEP\n 100\n");
  fprintf(fout2, "ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS\n 20\n");
  fprintf(fout2, "ITEM: ATOMS id type x y z\n");
  char buffer[1024];

  fgets(buffer, 1024, psf);

  int i = 0;

    for(i=0 ; (i<ROW) && (psf != NULL); i++)
    {
    fscanf (psf,"%*8d%*4s%*4d%*6s%*5s%*6s%11f%*14f%*12d", &q[i]);
    fscanf (pdb,"%*4s%*7d%*5s%*4s%*6d%12f%8f%8f%*6f%*6f%*9s", &x[i], &y[i], &z[i]);
    }

    for (t=0; t<100; t++)
    {
      //F = 0.0;
      v = F/gamma;
      shift = v*t;
      x[i] = x[i] + shift;
      y[i] = y[i] + shift;
      z[i] = z[i] + shift;
      for(i=0; i<ROW; i++)
      {
       Fx = Fy = Fz = F = 0.0;
       // Loop over other charges to compute force on this charge
        for (j=0 ; j<ROW ; j++)
        {
        //simply skip this itearation
          if(i == j)
           continue;
         // Compute the components of vector distance between two charges
          dx = x[i] - x[j];
          dy = y[i] - y[j];
          dz = z[i] - z[j];
           R = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);

           // Compute the x and y components of the force between
           // these two charges using Coulomb's law
          Fx += Constant*q[i]*q[j]*dx/(R*R*R);
          Fy += Constant*q[i]*q[j]*dy/(R*R*R);
          Fz += Constant*q[i]*q[j]*dz/(R*R*R);
       }

          F = sqrt(Fx*Fx + Fy*Fy + Fz*Fz);

     fprintf(fout, "%d %3.3g %3.3g %3.3g %3.3g\n", i+1, Fx, Fy, Fz, F);
     //fprintf(fout2, "%d %3.3g %3.3g %3.3g\n", i+1, x[i], y[i], z[i]);
     }
   fprintf(fout2, "%d %3.3g %3.3g %3.3g\n", i, x[i], y[i], z[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would change in your code:

- Epsilon and Constant should be declared as constants:
  "#define Epsilon0 8.85e-12"
  "#define Constant (1/(4*pi*Epsilon0))""
- Move the "i != j" inside the loop. That would prevent the loop from stopping if you hit that condition. You would just be skipping that iteration instead of stopping completely.
- You don't really need the xi, yi , zij, Fx, Fy, Fz, Rij arrays. You can use simple variables as placeholders instead.
- During each iteration of the inner loop, you would be calculating the partial force du to bead j. You need to add that force to the cumulative force.
  In order to do that you can declare Fx, Fy and Fz outside of the loops, initialize the 3 variable to 0 inside the first loop and then add partial forces inside the inner loop.
- Move the fprintf outside of the inner loop (but keep it inside the external loop)

**UPDATE**

This code does not handle I/O errors

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define Epsilon0 8.85e-12   // Permittivity of free space (C^2/(N m^2))
    #define Constant (1/(4*M_PI*Epsilon0))  // Useful constant

    #define ROW 20

    int row, col, j;
    float x[20], y[20], z[20], q[20], dx, dy, dz, R, Fx, Fy, Fz, F;

    int main()
    {
      FILE *psf=fopen("atom.psf", "r");
      FILE *pdb=fopen("beads.pdb", "r");
      FILE *fout=fopen("out.txt", "w");
      char buffer[1024];

      fgets(buffer, 1024, psf);

      int i = 0;

      for( ; (i<ROW) && (psf != NULL); i++)
      {
        fscanf (psf,"%*8d%*4s%*4d%*6s%*5s%*6s%11f%*14f%*12d", &q[i]);
        fscanf (pdb,"%*4s%*7d%*5s%*4s%*6d%12f%8f%8f%*6f%*6f%*9s", &x[i], &y[i], &z[i]);
      }

      for(i=0; i<ROW; i++)
      {
        Fx = Fy = Fz = F = 0.0;
        // Loop over other charges to compute force on this charge
        for (j=0 ; j<ROW ; j++)
        {
          //simply skip this itearation
          if(i == j)
            continue;
          // Compute the components of vector distance between two charges
          dx = x[i] - x[j];
          dy = y[i] - y[j];
          dz = z[i] - z[j];
          R = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);

          // Compute the x and y components of the force between
          // these two charges using Coulomb's law
          Fx += Constant*q[i]*q[j]*dx/(R*R*R);
          Fy += Constant*q[i]*q[j]*dy/(R*R*R);
          Fz += Constant*q[i]*q[j]*dz/(R*R*R);
        }

        F = sqrt(Fx*Fx + Fy*Fy + Fz*Fz);

        fprintf(fout, "%d %g %g %g, %g\n", i+1, Fx, Fy, Fz, F);
      }
    }
```

Comment: F = sqrt(Fx*Fx + Fy*Fy + Fz*Fz)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I am trying to implement that. I also wanted to work without arrays. But if I declare them as simple variables such as x,y,z and q then how I calculate the difference xi-xj, yi-yj and so on? Can you please help?

Comment: @nabaneetamukhopadhyay Code is above :-) I kept your logic. It still does not handle the I/O errors properly and the number of beads is still a constant. Also please keep in mind that Fij is equal to Fji, which means the current implementation is calculating the same forces twice. I'll be sharing a dynamic programming-based implementation tomorrow. Hope it helps

Comment: @nabaneetamukhopadhyay I'm new to the website so I could not put a comment on David's solution. Please remember that ||F1+F2|| <= ||F1|| + ||F2||. You can't simply increment the total force in each iteration. That would only work if all the forces are unidimensional. You have to calculate Fx, Fy and Fz separately inside the inner loop and then at the end you would be able to calculate the total value of the force.

Comment: Than you so much. I was looking for something simpler as you did. I was thinking since x[i] are in array then dx has to be in array. Silly me! I have edited my code in the question above.  However, I have a new query. I need to write the coordinates of 20 atoms after each timestep (t=0 to 100). I added another for loop for t on top of previous ones. But if I print inside the 2nd loop then it is wrong. If I print outside the 2nd loop then I will get the position for only the 20th atom. I am sure I am missing something very simple here. Please help!

Comment: @nabaneetamukhopadhyay Try moving the lines to calculate v, shift, x[i], y[i], z[i] right after the line where you're calculating F. The same thing applies to the fprintf.
F = sqrt(Fx*Fx + Fy*Fy + Fz*Fz);
v = F/gamma;
shift = v*t;
x[i] = x[i] + shift;
y[i] = y[i] + shift;
z[i] = z[i] + shift;
fprintf(fout, "%d %3.3g %3.3g %3.3g %3.3g\n", i+1, Fx, Fy, Fz, F);
fprintf(fout2, "%d %3.3g %3.3g %3.3g\n", i, x[i], y[i], z[i]);

Let me know if it works. I'm not in front of my computer so I can't test it myself

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a situation where instead of attempting to keep track of numerous separate arrays containing various information, life can be made a lot easier if you simply create a `struct` that captures the needed information for each *bead* and then create a single *array of struct*. For example, you want to capture the x,y,z position, charge, and component forces acting on each bead. (I included the total force as well, but that is optional). Your `struct` for each bead (I called it `beads`) could be as simple as:

```
typedef struct {
    float x, y, z, chrg, fx, fy, fz, f;
} beads;
```

In your code, you simply create an array of `beads` (one for each bead you need information on). For example, creating an array of beads with `20` elements, you could do something like the following:

```
#define Eo 8.85e-12F
#define KEair (1/(4*M_PI*Eo))

enum { NATM = 20, MAXL = 128 };  /* constants for number of beads/line len */
...
    beads atoms[NATM] = {{ .x = 0.0 }};
```

Now we have an array of struct called `atoms` to store information in. You can read information from each of your files and store the `x, y, z` positions for each bead as well as the `charge`. Then you can compute the force acting on each bead by computing the force due to every other bead and summing the information in the remaining force component and total members of each struct. You may do something like:

```
    for (i = 0; i < NATM; i++) {                /* for each bead */
        for (size_t j = 0; j < NATM; j++) {     /* compute force from every other */
            if (i == j) continue;               /* excluding itself */
            float dx = atoms[j].x - atoms[i].x, /* calculate component distances */
                  dy = atoms[j].y - atoms[i].y,
                  dz = atoms[j].z - atoms[i].z,
                  d  = sqrt (dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz); /* total distance */
            
            /* compute component and total forces acting on each bead (sum) */
            atoms[i].fx += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg * dx)/(d * d * d);
            atoms[i].fy += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg * dy)/(d * d * d);
            atoms[i].fz += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg * dz)/(d * d * d);
            atoms[i].f  += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg)/(d * d);
        }
    }
```

(you can confirm the approach to the sum at [**System of discrete charges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#System_of_discrete_charges))

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define Eo 8.85e-12F
#define KEair (1/(4*M_PI*Eo))

enum { NATM = 20, MAXL = 128 };

typedef struct {
    float x, y, z, chrg, fx, fy, fz, f;
} beads;

FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode);
float sqrt_fisr (float x);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    beads atoms[NATM] = {{ .x = 0.0 }};
    size_t i;
    char buf[MAXL] = "";    /* open/read atom.psf */
    FILE *fp = xfopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "dat/atom.psf", "r");
    
    fgets (buf, MAXL, fp);  /* read/discard 1st line */
    for (i = 0; i < NATM && fgets (buf, MAXL, fp); i++) { /* read/parse data */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %f", &atoms[i].chrg) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: read of charge failed, atom[%zu].\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);
    if (i != NATM) {    /* validate NATM lines read */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: only '%zu' charge values read.\n", i);
        return 1;
    }
        /* open/read beads.pdb */
    fp = xfopen (argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "dat/beads.pdb", "r");
    
    for (i = 0; i < NATM && fgets (buf, MAXL, fp); i++) { /* read/parse data */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %f %f %f", &atoms[i].x,
            &atoms[i].y, &atoms[i].z) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: read of position failed, atom[%zu].\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);
    if (i != NATM) {    /* validate NATM lines read */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: only '%zu' position values read.\n", i);
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < NATM; i++) {                /* for each bead */
        for (size_t j = 0; j < NATM; j++) {     /* compute force from every other */
            if (i == j) continue;               /* excluding itself */
            float dx = atoms[j].x - atoms[i].x, /* calculate component distances */
                  dy = atoms[j].y - atoms[i].y,
                  dz = atoms[j].z - atoms[i].z,
                  d  = sqrt (dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz); /* total distance */
            
            /* compute component and total forces acting on each bead (sum) */
            atoms[i].fx += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg * dx)/(d * d * d);
            atoms[i].fy += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg * dy)/(d * d * d);
            atoms[i].fz += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg * dz)/(d * d * d);
            atoms[i].f  += (KEair * atoms[i].chrg *atoms[j].chrg)/(d * d);
        }
    }
        
    for (i = 0; i < NATM; i++)  /* output forces on each bead (component and total) */
        printf (" atom[%2zu]  %5.2f  %5.2f  %5.2f   %+.2f   %15.2f  %15.2f  %5.2f  %15.2f\n",
                i, atoms[i].x, atoms[i].y, atoms[i].z, atoms[i].chrg,
                atoms[i].fx, atoms[i].fy, atoms[i].fz, atoms[i].f);
    
    return 0;
}

/** simple fopen with error check */
FILE *xfopen (const char *fn, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, mode);

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xfopen() error: file open failed '%s'.\n", fn);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fp;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/coulomb
 atom[ 0]   1.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00    13844509696.00     -13956823.00   0.00   13831302144.00
 atom[ 1]   2.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00     4741866496.00     -13982750.00   0.00   22712082432.00
 atom[ 2]   3.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00     2353591552.00     -14002249.00   0.00   24819521536.00
 atom[ 3]   4.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00     1171170304.00     -14015272.00   0.00   25635096576.00
 atom[ 4]   5.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00      359584800.00     -14021791.00   0.00   25947308032.00
 atom[ 5]   6.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00     -359584608.00     -14021791.00   0.00   25947308032.00
 atom[ 6]   7.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00    -1171170944.00     -14015272.00   0.00   25635096576.00
 atom[ 7]   8.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00    -2353592320.00     -14002249.00   0.00   24819521536.00
 atom[ 8]   9.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00    -4741866496.00     -13982751.00   0.00   22712082432.00
 atom[ 9]  10.00   0.00   0.00   +1.00   -13844510720.00     -13956824.00   0.00   13831303168.00
 atom[10]   1.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00    13844507648.00      13956823.00   0.00   13831302144.00
 atom[11]   2.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00     4741867008.00      13982750.00   0.00   22712080384.00
 atom[12]   3.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00     2353592064.00      14002249.00   0.00   24819521536.00
 atom[13]   4.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00     1171170944.00      14015272.00   0.00   25635096576.00
 atom[14]   5.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00      359585056.00      14021791.00   0.00   25947308032.00
 atom[15]   6.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00     -359584864.00      14021791.00   0.00   25947308032.00
 atom[16]   7.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00    -1171170560.00      14015272.00   0.00   25635096576.00
 atom[17]   8.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00    -2353591808.00      14002249.00   0.00   24819521536.00
 atom[18]   9.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00    -4741867008.00      13982751.00   0.00   22712080384.00
 atom[19]  10.00  80.00   0.00   -1.00   -13844509696.00      13956824.00   0.00   13831304192.00
```

Looking at the output graphically, the forces increase from the end to a maximum in the center of each string or beads -- that checks, and the forces acting upon the beads in the X-direction is the greatest at each end and reverses direction at midpoint -- also a check. For example:

**Total Force Acting on Each Bead**

[image]

**Forces acting in the X direction on Each Bead**

[image]

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Sometime very, very long ago, I recall making friends with Ohm, Coulomb, Faraday, Maxwell, Tesla, et. al. The strange thing is -- I actually recall enjoying it `:)`

Comment: Thanks @David. That actually helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help

The for loop,

```
    `for (j = 0; j<ROW && i != j; j++)`
```

Will exit when `i == j` as the loop condition is false. For example when i is 1 will only iterate through the loop once, when j is 0.

Use if statement inside the for loop to skip the current charge,  i.e when `i == j`

```
    for (j = 0; j<ROW ; j++)
     {
        if (i != j) 
        {
           DO CALCULATION... `
```

Also,  think that `Fx[i]` will only ever have store the force due to an single `j` charge as it is assignment for each iteration rather than a sum.

Consider changing to accumlate for each interation,  i.e. `Fx[i] +=` then calculate `F[i]` when this `for` loop has completed

Comment: What is the difference if I use the i != j condition in for loop condition and separately under if condition? Earlier I was using the if loop as you suggested but I didn't see any difference in the output.

Comment: Once the condition is `j<ROW & &  i ! = j` is false the loop exits and moves onto the next `i`,  place printf inside the loop to view what happens

Comment: For the printf just to display the i and j values rather than the output